# Firebird 2.5 – при select в view, ошибка “cannot update read-only view”

Tags: delphi, firebird

Создал view,

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW BOSS_DEPARTMENT(
    ID,
    FIO)
AS
select ID, (FAMILY_NAME ||' '|| Left(NAME,1)||'.'||Left(PATRONYMIC_NAME,1)||'.') as FIO
from USERS_DATA 
;
```

Все работает.

При добавлении к запросу сортировки «*order by FAMILY_NAME*» (в *view*): В *IBExpert* все работает замечательно, но когда при проектирование (в *Delphi*) в DataSet (с учетом сортировки), выкидывается ошибка:
«

> raised exception class EIBInterBaseError with message 'cannot update
>   read-only view BOSS_DEPARTMENT'

»
Я не собираюсь его модифицировать, откуда такая ошибка?

Comment: Определил, что если с DataSet, убрать все запросы кроме запроса "Refresh", то все начинает работать.
Ну всеравно не понятно **причем тут "order by"?** (ну запросы "модификации", "вставки" и "удаления" - понятно)

Answer (score 1):

Все представления в Firebird делятся на изменяемые и неизменяемые. Изменяемым является представление, в котором:

1. только одна таблица (без join и union);
2. нет подзапросов;
3. нет агрегатных функций (count, sum и пр.);
4. нет группировки и **сортировки**;
5. нет distinct;
6. все поля таблицы, *не* упомянутые в запросе, допускают null

Неизменямое представление можно превратить в изменяемое с помощью триггеров.

Добавив order by, ты превратил изменяемое представление в неизменяемое. А датасет-то пытается построить модифицирующие запросы...